# Add new view with specific Segue transition

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5

```
PinViewController *k_View = [[PinViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PinViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:k_View];
[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion: nil];
NSString *addr = sender.titleLabel.text;
[k_View showPinView:addr];
```

This is my code. The new view is added programmatically, so I can't just use the GUI to select what type of segue effect I want. I would like to use the Segue that uses the transition "Cross Disolve", how would I go about doing that in code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any segue. just add:

```
navigationController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
```

Before calling presentViewController:animated:completion: and it should do the trick. 
See modalTransitionStyle and modalPresentationStyle in the [UIViewController reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked perfectly! Sorry, I cant give you a vote up (my reputation is not good enough yet)